# Deciphering Python Mypy Reports

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I tried to read `mypy` reports, but do not quite understand how...

So, on `/tmp/tmp_py/`, I created a dummy file, as follows:

```
def kuki(x):
    print("kuki")
    return "kuki"

def buki(x: str) -> int:
    print(333333)
    return 33
```

Now I run `mypy --strict --txt-report=/tmp /tmp/tmp_py/`.

I expected to see that 1 function is OK (the `buki` function), and one is missing type hints (the `kuki` function). As such, I also expected to see statistics that says something like: "50% OK".

What I got was:

```
Mypy Type Check Coverage Summary
================================

Script: index

+--+-------------------+-------+
| Module | Imprecision       | Lines |
+--+-------------------+-------+
+--+-------------------+-------+
| Total |   0.00% imprecise | 0 LOC |
+--+-------------------+-------+
```

questions at this point are:

1. why 0 lines of code (I guess LOC stands for Lines Of Code)?
2. why 0.00% imprecide? I would expect 50%...

anyways, realising it does not yield the results I am looking for, I tried: `mypy --strict --linecount-report=/tmp /tmp/tmp_py/`. This has produced the encrypted output:

```
      5      11      1      2 total
      5      11      1      2 tmp_py.a
      0       0      0      0 tmp_py
```

so more questions arise:

1. but how does that reads?
2. what does the columns mean?

going forward, I tried: `mypy --strict --linecoverage-report=/tmp /tmp/tmp_py/`. This had produced an even more encrypted output:

```
{
  "lines": {
    "/tmp/tmp_py/a.py": [
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9,
      10,
      11
    ],
    "/tmp/tmp_py/__init__.py": []
  }
}
```

and even more questions:

1. what is this array of numbers means?
2. what are the values it holds?

so then I turned to: `mypy --strict --lineprecision-report=/tmp /tmp/tmp_py/`. It produced no output whatsoever...

and so, like, Hhhh???

Does anyone know how to decipher those reports? links to documentation would be great. does anyone understand why `lineprecision-report` produced no output? and finally, in case `mypy` cannot produce me with the stats I am looking for (which are, I think, pretty basic - how many functions are OK, and how many are "broken") - does anyone know or recommend of other tool that can provide these stats?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What `mypy` version do you use? I get `42.86% imprecise` when evaluating your example with v0.770. Although admitted, the reports are somewhat edgy.

Comment: @hoefling, thanks for your comment.
Same `mypy` version:
`mypy --version` gives `mypy 0.770`.
Maybe python version? I am using Python 3.6.8. 
Maybe OS? I am using MacOS, Catalina 10.15.4.
But 42.86% is even more odd... Like, one would expect 50%...

Familiar with other tools that might do the job right?